# Make app.Dialog shadow darker

Tags: android, android-layout, dialog, android-styles

How do you make background shadow of custom `app.Dialog` darker?

**Expectation**:

[image]

**Reality**:

[image]

What I tried:

1) `MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog (mContext);
   dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLACK));
   dialog.show();`

2) `MyDialog  dialog = new MyDialog (mContext, R.style.NewDialog);
   dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLACK));
   dialog.show();`

where `R.style.NewDialog`:

```
<!-- This style removes shadow but I need to make it darker.-->
<!-- Don't know which parameter needed to change for that-->
<style name="NewDialog"> 
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following custom class It may Be work,

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;

import com.stackexmples.R;

/**
 * Created by windws on 30-Mar-16.
 */
public class AlertDFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                // Set Dialog Icon
                .setIcon(R.drawable.androidhappy)
                        // Set Dialog Title
                .setTitle("Alert DialogFragment")
                        // Set Dialog Message
                .setMessage("Alert DialogFragment Tutorial")

                        // Positive button
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // Do something else
                    }
                })

                        // Negative Button
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // Do something else
                    }
                }).create();
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Window window = getDialog().getWindow();
        window.setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
    }
}
```

Window window = getDialog().getWindow();
        window.setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);

is not work in onCreate() it work onStart()

Comment: No changes. Seems like its the same as in 1) `dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLACK));`

Comment: How do I display this dialog?

Comment: AlertDFragment alertDFragment=new AlertDFragment();
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");

Comment: Okay, I've launched it. But `Window window = getDialog().getWindow();
        window.setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.black);` changed the background of AlertDialog to black and not the shadow